# Set Expiry of Kubernetes service tokens

Tags: kubernetes, jwt, credentials

Is there a way to configure Kubernetes SetviceAccount tokens to expire? Following the [documentation these tokens are JWT](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#service-account-tokens) (as I was able to also check it using a [JWT debugger](https://jwt.io/#debugger-io)). [Following the specification JWT specifies expiration](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.4) but so far I was not able to find out how I can convince Kubernetes create tokens with this header.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Which version of k8s are you running and where is it located?

Comment: We're running kubernetes 1.16 and it is running in AWS EKS.

Answer (score 4):

Currently the default service account JWT tokens in Kubernetes are considered as “forever” tokens. They don’t expire and are valid for as long as the service account exists. I fear that your goal might nor be possible to achieve from the Kubernetes side.

I am posting this answer as a community wiki. Feel free to expand it if you know how to approach it from another side.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

From the docs [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/#service-account-token-volume-projection) you can use `expirationSeconds` to set expiry time of the JWT token. This property is not configurable on the default service account token.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: nginx
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/tokens
      name: vault-token
  serviceAccountName: build-robot
  volumes:
  - name: vault-token
    projected:
      sources:
      - serviceAccountToken:
          path: vault-token
          expirationSeconds: 7200
          audience: vault
```

Comment: It does not solve my issue with default service account tokens (ones that are not bound to a pod) but I see the meaning. :-(